# Trying to get Values back from a Flask template into my Python with MongoDB as Database

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, flask

i'm trying to get some data into an Flask application. Please keep in mind that I am new at this. I am trying to make a row of selections. I am using Dropdown boxes and also using Bootstrap.

In my Flask app (index.py) i'm getting some values. My collections in the MongoDB:

```
coll = db.collection_names()

try:
    return flask.render_template('pricHistory.html', title=title, pageType=pageType, coll=coll)
except Exception as e:
    return str("Exception is been handled at Price-History: ", e)
```

> on the webpage i use something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group first">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Collections <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" onclick>
        {% for i in coll %}                 
            {% if i == "system.indexes" %}

            {% else %}
            <li class="test"><a href="#">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can i catch the selected value and use it in my index.py again to get the second Dropdown. Because the Second Dropdown should have DOCUMENTS in the mongoDB by the Choice of the First Dropdown (COLLECTION).

> The second is similar. Example of what i have is:

```
<div class="btn-group second">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        CPU <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" onclick>
        {% for i in cpu %}
            <li class="test"><a href="#">{{ i }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with HTML? You need to use a <form> (http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_forms.asp) and then on the flask side use a request.args.get() if you're doing a GET request to pull in the data.

Comment: Also why do you have thay try-except block when you render the template?